# Stratified Random Sampling Excel

Tags: random, sampling

I have a large data set, let's say 10,000 line items of animal observations.

There are 3 categories:
1. Species: values can be either Lion, Zebra or Buffalo
2. Age: value can be either Young or Adult
3. Social type: value can be either Alone or Group

The statistics for the whole data set are as follows:
Species: Lion (20%), Zebra (40%), Buffalo (40%)
Age: Young (30%), Old (70%)
Social type: Alone (45%), Group (55%)

I need to perform random stratified sampling of the data set to achieve a sample size of 100 line items.

My sample would need to reflect the statistics of the population.

Is there a way to achieve this without VBA?

Thank you

Comment: Hi user3438321, welcome to Stackoverflow. Is there a reason why you are trying to avoid VBA?

Comment: Hi Francis, I am just not that confident with VBA.. I can muddle my way through it though. If there is a reasonably simple solution then I am happy to have a go - it's just my question above is a very simplified version of the actual problem and I need to be able to scale it! Thanks a lot, Jack

Comment: Assuming no VBA, maybe you can assign a random number (using `=rand()`) to each one of the 10k line items and a new label/dimension (d) which is a unique combination of species, age, social type. For instance, `Lion, Young, Alone` = 20% * 30% * 45% = 2.7% of sample/population, etc. 3 species * 2 ages * 2 social types = 12 unique combinations I think. Maybe next would be to rank each random number (from earlier) within its 'group' (combination of species, age, social type).

Comment: Once you've got random numbers, labels and ranks assigned, you could then get the top X items by rank (where X = sample size * product percentage for that label as calculated in previous comment) for each of the 12 unique labels/groups.

Comment: Maybe my approach is flawed in some way, but I can't see how at the moment (maybe rank collisions due to rand() producing duplicate numbers, though unlikely). Overall, might be easier using VBA.

Answer (score 0):

There's a video tutorial here on how to do random stratified sampling on Excel WITHOUT programming.

It involves generating a random column, and then sorting column or columns to your requirements, and sorting the random column last.

It's in the 4:12 mark that the user explains how to do it with multi-columns.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=70qEBD3-88U